# Add a third-party framework to a compiled app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, frameworks

I'm trying to add a third-party framework to my OS X app. It's a framework called MapKit, and it was specifically built for OS X. I added the framework to the "Copy Files" section of Xcode (see screenshot below). However, when I create an archive of my app and export it to my desktop, launching it causes a crash with the following error:

```
Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @loader_path/../Frameworks/MapKit.framework/Versions/A/MapKit
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/Desktop/Example.app/Contents/MacOS/Example
  Reason: image not found
```

Adding the framework to Xcode:

[image]

Am I not copying the framework correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, in `Copy Files` phase you've created, change `Destination` to `Frameworks`